# how fetch specific values from String in db2 query

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

my table has value like this "lowValue=100,upperValue=200".

i tried substr and trim function to trim lowValue= and upperValue= text. nothing worked for me

```
Select contantName,constantValue from Test where contantName="test1"; 

-------------------------------------------------
 contantName         constantValue
-------------------------------------------------
 test1               lowValue=100,upperValue=200
-------------------------------------------------
```

How to get only lowValue and highvalue in select query.

i want output to fetch only numbers from the constant value 100 and 200.

Answer (score 0):

select contantName, REPLACE(REPLACE(constantValue,'lowValue=',''), 'upperValue=','') from Test where contantName="test1";

Comment: i wanted to fetch only 100 and only 200

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution for the sample shown

```
WITH test (constantValue) AS ( 
SELECT 'lowValue=1000,upperValue=20000' AS constantValue FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
SELECT constantValue
     , substr(constantValue, posstr(constantValue, 'lowValue=') + 9 , posstr(constantValue, ',') - (posstr(constantValue, '=')+1)) AS lowvalue
     , substr(constantValue, posstr(constantValue, 'upperValue=') + 11 , length(constantValue) - (posstr(constantValue, 'upperValue=')+10)) AS uppervalue
FROM test
```

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP_SUBSTR can do it

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\blowValue=(\d+)', 1, 1, 'c', 1) as "lowValue",
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '\bupperValue=(\d+)', 1, 1, 'c', 1) as "upperValue"  
FROM (VALUES 'lowValue=54321,upperValue=123') AS base (value)
```